# validating join table in case of nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, nested-attributes, join

I have a rails4 app and just realized I forgot to add validation to my `IndustryProducts` table via finding a db object without `product_id`.

A user can create a `product` in the product form that accepts `nested_attributes` for choosing one or more `industries` via `collection_select`. Everything worked fine till now, but as I tried to add `presence` validations in the `IndustryProducts` table to the foreign key fields (`product_id` and `industry_id`) I got error messages on submitting the form after choosing 1 or more industries: `Industry products product can not be blank` and `Industry products is invalid`. If I choose nothing then of course I get the message to choose at least one.

What did I miss? How can I validate that both the `product_id` and `industry_id` are present in the `IndustryProducts` table?

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :industry_products, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :industries, through: :industry_products

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :industry_products, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true

  validates_associated :industry_products
end

class Industry < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :industry_products
  has_many :products, through: :industry_products

  #accepts_nested_attributes_for :industry_products #THIS LINE MAKES NO DIFFERENCE; tried with and without it

  validates :name, presence: { messsage: "can not be blank" }
end


class IndustryProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :industry
  #accepts_nested_attributes_for :industry #THIS LINE NEITHER MAKES DIFF; tried with and without it


  #IF I PUT THESE LINES IN THEN I GET THE ERRORS I MENTIONED ABOVE    
  validates :product, presence: { message: "can not be blank" }
  validates :industry, presence: { message: "can not be blank" }
end
```

product form:

```
<%= form_for @product,....
  <%= f.collection_select :industry_ids, Industry.all.order(name: :asc), :id, :name, {}, { multiple: true, class: "form-control" } %>
.....
```

strong_params for product:

```
params.require(:product).permit( :name,  industry_ids: [], .....)
```

params sent over with POST request:

```
"product"=>{"name"=>"asdfasfasdfqqqq", "industry_ids"=>["4", "8"], "description"=>"", .........}
```

controller

```
def new
  @product = Product.new
  @product.industry_products.build
end

def create
  @product = current_user.products.new(product_params)
  if @product.save
  ......
end
```

Comment: can you show your controller action?

Comment: sebsonic2o, I added it.

Comment: I think the issue here is using `validates_associated :industry_products` but then only providing the through association's IDs. As a debugging step, if you remove that do the right records get saved?

Comment: I tried it, in this case I only get the `Industry products product can not be blank` error message. I was thinking about the empty string in the params, can that cause the problem? Btw. I don't really get why the first one in the array is empty.

Comment: I think you may want to add { include_hidden: false } in your collection select. The blank in the industry_ids param may be the culprit...

Comment: Do you want me to write an answer with { include_hidden: false } added to collection_select?

Comment: I tried it but didn't work this way `params: "industry_ids"=>["4"]`. It's something else.

Comment: At least, this one is out of the way.

Comment: The problem is with the `validates :product, presence: { message: "can not be blank" }` in the `industry_products`. If I take it out then it works. But I don't get it how the `product` would be blank, since that is the parent object.

Comment: sebsonic2o, I'd recommend not to use `{include_hidden: false}`. I don't know why but it screwed up my update validations. If I take off all the industries that I've chosen on creation in the collection form I don't get error messages, the product gets saved and keeps the old industries that were chosen before. It's super weird.

Answer (score 2):

I had to add `inverse_of: :product` in the product model like this and now everything works fine:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :industry_products, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :product
  .......
```